# Create two column footer Using div?

Tags: css, xhtml, html

How do I create a two column footer using div only? (tableless)

The footer is 980px it should contain....

Copyright 2010 xyz.com (left side)

About us | privacy | terms  (right side)

Comment: google for 'two column css layout'

Comment: @meder: Googling for two-column css layout provides a zillion results, of which very few have to do with footers. Offer a little good faith in the poster first.

Comment: footers arent "special", they are elements just like any other. it would be no different than a wrapper with content/sidebar columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it something like this:

CSS:

```
.Footer_outer{
width: 980px;
border: 1px solid;
}

.Footer_inner_left{
width: 49%;
Float: left;
display:inline;
}

.Footer_inner_right{
width: 49%;
Float: right;
display:inline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="Footer_outer">
  <div class="Footer_inner_left">Copyright 2010 xyz.com </div>
  <div class="Footer_inner_right">About us | privacy | terms </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this would render a 982px combined width element. in addition, floats aren't being contained.

Answer (score 2):

In your css:

```
#footerLeft { width: 47%; float: left; display: block; 50px;}
#footerRight { width: 47%; float: right; display: block; height: 50px; }
#footer { width: 100%; height: 100% width: 980px; }
```

Html:

```
<div id="footer">
<div id="footerLeft">Copyright 2010 xyz.com</div>
<div id="footerRight">About Us | Privacy | terms </div>
</div>
```

Check out http://www.blueprintcss.org/ Framework, it will make life easier.

Comment: display:block isnt necessary, width: 100% followed by 980px is redundant, doubt the height:100% does anything.

Comment: plus you aren't containing floats.

Comment: correct - don't need the width:100% in the #footer -- I should have proofed before posting.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
#footer { overflow:hidden; width:980px; margin:0 auto; }
#footer #copy { float:left; display:inline; width:490px; }
#footer #links { float:right; display:inline; width:490px; }
```

html:

```
<div id="footer"><div id="copy">copyr..</div><div id="links">blah</div></div>
```